# keeps asking to install ubuntu 17.10 via USB

Tags: system-installation

I installed ubuntu on my usb. I turned my laptop off and turn it on, and I see the options to try ubuntu without installing and install ubuntu etc.  I choose install ubuntu and installed alongside windows boot.  But when I finish installing everything and restart the computer and try to go into the ubuntu boot. It asks me again try ubuntu without installing and install ubuntu etc. How do I go into the ubuntu I installed because it keeps asking me to install it.

Thank you in advance,

-Jose Guerrero

Comment: maybe it is as simple as taking out your usb drive out of the slot?

Comment: doesn't solve the problem

Comment: What happens, when you try to boot after unplugging the USB drive? Please describe it with as many details as possible. Otherwise we can only guess. Probably we have to ask more questions ...

Comment: it goes directly to windows operating system. Reason for that is because it will not boot automatically from my USB so i press F12 eachtime to acccess ubuntu. But if i do that even after installing it already it asks me to install again. If i unplug the usb and turn my pc on it will just go to windows

Comment: So it seems your installation failed. You can boot from the USB drive, but that is the live system, not the installed system. Please describe your computer, brand name and model, and the graphics chip/card (also brand name and model). When running Ubuntu from the USB drive, please open a terminal window and run the following command lines, `sudo lsblk -f` and `sudo lsblk -m` and `sudo parted -ls`; Edit the output into your original question and indent each line 4 spaces to render it as 'code'.

Comment: well when your system boots from usb it will ALWAYS ask to install or not. So no matter what you do, it will not be solved by inserting your USB drive.  Also, your version of Ubuntu is allready installed, the issue is that the windows boot screen doesn't show the option menu. I had this issue myself once in the past, but am not sure how to solve it anymore.  google how to correctly alter your windows boot screen for dual boot. also post us which versions of ubuntu and windows you are using.

Comment: Im using wondows 10 and ubuntu 17.10

Comment: Please edit your original question and post the output of the command lines in my previous question. We need that information in order to help you.